# Maven resource plugin exclude folder

Tags: java, maven

I just migrated my project to `Maven`. My project has'nt a structure compliant with Maven standard.

So, I have this problem: in my project resources and sources are in the same path *src*. What I try to say to Maven when creates the war is: *publish all resources under *src* excluding all java files and the folder main that is under *src**

My pom is:

```xml
    <build>
        <finalName>${customWarName}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>main/**/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
```

For java file all works fine, but not for folder exclusion.

I try also `<exclude>main/**/*.*</exclude>` or `<exclude>**/main/**</exclude>` or `<exclude>src/main/**</exclude>`  or `<exclude>main/**</exclude>`.

Nothings works.

Can anyone help me to understand how can I exclude this folder?

Comment: First step of a migration make it following the conventions which means follow the directory structure. That makes your life easier....  See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close.  Try this (untested):

```xml
<build>
  <finalName>${customWarName}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>main/**</exclude> <!-- try this -->
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```